# This is the first time we meet translation

Tags: translation

"This is the first time we meet" what is it in Japanese? Is it something like:

わたしははじめてやまださんにあいます。?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「わたしははじめてやまださんにあいます。」 is fine.

「わたしははじめてやまださんにおあいします。」 is more polite.

In either case, it would sound more natural if you omitted the わたしは part.  This just just how we speak.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:
「やまださんに お会いする / 会う のはこれが初めてです」